# What is the role of ios/build folder in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, build

I'm troubleshooting a React Native app and one article suggested deleting the `ios/build` folder, but didn't explain why. Does anyone know, in as much detail as you can, what the role of this folder is, how it's created, and what the implications are of deleting it?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually it's the code compiled into native. when you compile your code for example react-native run-ios , this command generate the compile and build code for ios and then run it on IOS simulator. its generated after compiling project.

Comment: @Jamil Thank you!

Comment: @Jamil in the article I read (https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2017/04/22/solving-react-natives-no-bundle-url-present-error/) it was saying that when the author ran `react-native run-ios`, it gave him an error, so he deleted the build folder and ran `react-native run-ios` again. If the build folder is the direct result of `react-native run-ios`, shouldn't he get the same behaviour both times?

Comment: Actually according to my understanding, when we run react-native run-ios, this will build the new changes only, while the code that was build and not changed remain the same. like if we rebuild the project form the xcode, this will regenerate the whole code regardless of the new and old code changes. its like replacing the build folder. similarly if we just Build from xcode, the new code will be build only.

Comment: So the owner of the blog kinda Rebuilt the code manually by deleting the build folder, so when he react-native run-ios, the compiler will look that no build folder found, and will rebuild from the start.

Answer (score 4):

> what the role of this build folder

Actually it's the code compiled into native. when you compile your code, for example react-native run-ios , this command compile and build code for ios and then run it on IOS simulator. its generated after compiling project.

> how it's created

When you run the app, the compiler will build this folder.

> and what the implications are of deleting it?

Then the compiler will build the whole project from start as the build folder for IOS or ANDROID is missing which is needed to run the native app.

I hope this helps in your understanding.

Answer (score 3):

`ios/build` folder is updated when the app is built. It contains several subfolders, each having its own use:

### Build/Products

Stores final build artifacts that are installed on Simulator or device.

### Build/Intermediates.noindex

Stores additional files used while building the app. These are cached to speed up subsequent builds. **Removing it will slow down the next build**.

### Index

Xcode performs indexing of project source code and stores the index in this folder. Index is used to speed up Xcode operation like search, quick navigation, refactoring. **Removing this will trigger indexing next time Xcode is opened**. However, Xcode index doesn't really affect React Native developer experience since you normally don't use Xcode much while developing RN apps.

### Logs

Stores logs collected while performing various tasks like building, testing, debugging etc.

### ModuleCache

Stores precompiled module files. Modules allow to reduce compile time of Xcode apps. **Removing this will slow down the next build.**

---

To summarize, ios/build folder contains final installation app files, auxiliary files and precompiled modules, various logs and source code index. The main implication of removing the build folder is that the next build will be slower than usual.